# hadoop log4j not working

Tags: hadoop, log4j, hadoop-yarn

My jobs are running successfully with Hadoop 2.6.0 but the logger is not working at all

I always see

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

yarn-site.xml has the directory with the log4j.properties file listed. I also tried passing it manually via `-Dlog4j.configuration` option.

the file is here: http://www.pastebin.ca/2966941

Comment: Can you post your log4j.properties file?

Comment: its the one that came with Hadoop 2.6.0, no changes. posting the file anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To enable AppSummaryLogging for the RM,

> set yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger to ,RMSUMMARY
>   in hadoop-env.sh

Try the above step as mentioned in log4j.properties. Not sure if it works.