# Hadoop log4j not working as No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory)

Tags: hadoop, log4j

I am working on developing mapreduce using eclipse , and trying to test it using hadoop 2.6.0 windows standalone mode.

But getting the below error for log4j,

How to fix the below appender problem,

No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory)

same problem as [hadoop log4j not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361264/hadoop-log4j-not-working) but no answer yet

Thanks ,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1- Create the file log4j.properties and put it in the location of

src/main/resources

the content of the log4j.properties

```
hadoop.root.logger=DEBUG, console
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
```

it happens because of the hadoop logging framework

Answer (score 2):

Create a log4j.properties file with something like the following:

```
hadoop.root.logger=DEBUG, console

log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
```